# Is content lazy loading possible with plain javascript without js libraries or frameworks?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Suppose I get huge data from API using fetch, and I would like to render the data in UI with the help of lazy loading using plain js. Is it possible? If so, can you give an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use a library as an example?

Comment: And of course it's possible. There's nothing special about libraries, they're just ordinary JS code. If it weren't possible, how would they do it?

Comment: It's just JS all the way down. 

Comment: @Shibumi, Can you please give an example or any relevant blog link. I'm new to JS.